# App closes on start when trying to run react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm facing some issues with running `react-native run-ios` on my react native project.

After the command the app as loading, black screen appears for a few seconds and then the app is closes.

Here is a log from WebStorm.

```
info Found Xcode workspace "Actors.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 11 (iOS 14.3)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Actors.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Actors -destination id=5508C928-BADB-4FE5-8426-9B1461397EC3")
(node:44088) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/michaelionia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Actors-gzwkhkgvbultrlcjeogpfwamtnzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Actors.app"
info Launching "org.name.Actors"
success Successfully launched the app on the simulator
```

When I'm running `react-native run-android` the app workings good with all libraries.

I've tried to run the project from xCode , but facing the same issue , the app opens with back screen and 0 Errors.

Here is a log from xcode

```
2021-02-15 10:43:06.728730+0200 Actors[44637:1250270] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2021-02-15 10:43:06.728839+0200 Actors[44637:1250270] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2021-02-15 10:43:06.866897+0200 Actors[44637:1251130] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2021-02-15 10:43:06.904031+0200 Actors[44637:1250270] [native] Running application main ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2021-02-15 10:43:06.930218+0200 Actors[44637:1250270] [native] 'SplashScreen.storyboard' file is missing. Fallbacking to 'SplashScreen.xib' file.
2021-02-15 10:43:06.930558+0200 Actors[44637:1250270] [native] 'SplashScreen.xib' file is missing - 'expo-splash-screen' will not work as expected.
2021-02-15 10:43:06.966657+0200 Actors[44637:1250270] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ERR_NO_SPLASH_SCREEN', reason: 'Couln't locate neither 'SplashScreen.storyboard' file nor 'SplashScreen.xib' file. Create one of these in the project to make 'expo-splash-screen' work (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#-configure-ios).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20420af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Actors                              0x0000000101dc49e9 -[EXSplashScreenViewNativeProvider createSplashScreenView] + 2185
    3   Actors                              0x0000000101dc19bd -[EXSplashScreenController initWithViewController:splashScreenViewProvider:] + 221
    4   Actors                              0x0000000101dc3878 -[EXSplashScreenService showSplashScreenFor:splashScreenViewProvider:successCallback:failureCallback:] + 312
    5   Actors                              0x0000000101dc36a5 -[EXSplashScreenService showSplashScreenFor:] + 149
    6   Actors                              0x0000000101dc4075 -[EXSplashScreenService application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 181
    7   Actors                              0x00000001021fdc9c -[UMAppDelegateWrapper application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 476
    8   Actors                              0x0000000101d8567e -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 574
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2468d0f1 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 232
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2468ec73 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3919
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24694681 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1237
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cbd907 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2424bdb6 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 88
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cbe416 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cbdeda -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 474
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cbe247 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 819
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cbdadb -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 345
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cc5d73 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 178
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff241556ab +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 871
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2426865e _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23cc5a79 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 361
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23ae896f __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 797
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23ae7419 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 253
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23ae85a8 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 208
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24692b20 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 508
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2417dab7 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 358
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25aa20ae -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 391
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25acab41 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.176 + 102
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25aafad5 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 209
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25aca80f __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001035329c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103535910 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 295
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25af07a5 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25af048b -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 433
    35  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25af0950 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038f38a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038f282 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038e764 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 248
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20388f2f __CFRunLoopRun + 878
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203886d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2bededb3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    42  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24690e0b -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    43  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24695cbc UIApplicationMain + 101
    44  Actors                              0x0000000101d85eb0 main + 112
    45  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff202593e9 start + 1
    46  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ERR_NO_SPLASH_SCREEN', reason: 'Couln't locate neither 'SplashScreen.storyboard' file nor 'SplashScreen.xib' file. Create one of these in the project to make 'expo-splash-screen' work (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#-configure-ios).'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11 (5508C928-BADB-4FE5-8426-9B1461397EC3) - Runtime: iOS 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 11
(lldb) .
```

I've tried to delete podfile.log and run pod install from ios directory.

Comment: check if file called SplashScreen.storyboard exists inside your ios project

Comment: Hi @HassanKandil, The file exist inside ios/projectName ...

Comment: try to: Remove application from the device-
Restart device-
Build again if all of that doesn't work delete derived data. Xcode Preference->Locationtab->Derived data

Comment: The error it throws tells you to go here:
https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#-configure-ios

It looks like your app is not configured correctly for iOS.

Comment: In XCode, switch to `General` tab and what is under `App Icons and Launch Images`?

Comment: Hi @LeriGogsadze , Under `App Icon and Lauch Images` I have AppIcon and SplashScreen

Answer (score 6):

In `Info.plist` find `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>`, right under this line you should see `<string>SplashScreen.storyboard</string>`, remove this `.storyboard` part and it will work.